# tidyverse solution for recoding several columnsinto new ones where column name suffixes increase by one

Tags: r, tidyverse, recode, across

This is only pseudo code, but let's assume I have 22 columns named from Q46x47_1 to Q46x47_22.

I now want to apply the following recode logic:

```
if Q46x47_1=0 Q46x47_2=0. 
if Q46x47_3=0 Q46x47_4=0. 
if Q46x47_5=0 Q46x47_6=0. 
if Q46x47_7=0 Q46x47_8=0. 
if Q46x47_9=0 Q46x47_10=0. 
if Q46x47_11=0 Q46x47_12=0. 
if Q46x47_13=0 Q46x47_14=0. 
if Q46x47_15=0 Q46x47_16=0. 
if Q46x47_17=0 Q46x47_18=0. 
if Q46x47_19=0 Q46x47_20=0. 
if Q46x47_21=0 Q46x47_22=0.
```

Of course, I don't want to type this by hand. So I was wondering if there's an elegant way to bulk recode this. I know of `across`, but I don't see a way how to pass each second variable with the increased suffix number.

So I started with:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(num_range(prefix = "Q46x47_", range = seq(1, 21, 2)), ~if_else(. == 0, ..., .)))
```

My problem is (given if_else could be used here) how to specify the `...` part in the if_else command where I need to pass the LHS column names.

Any ideas?

---

Short reproducible example with a subset of columns:

```
df <- data.frame(Q46x47_1 = c(1, 2, 0, 1, 0),
                 Q46x47_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 0),
                 Q46x47_3 = c(1, 2, 0, 1, 0),
                 Q46x47_4 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 0),
                 Q46x47_5 = c(1, 2, 0, 1, 0),
                 Q46x47_6 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, this is more easier

```
nm1 <- paste0("Q46x47_", seq(1, 21, by = 2))
nm2 <- paste0("Q46x47_", seq(2, 22, by = 2))
i1 <- df[nm1] == 0
df[nm2][i1] <- 0
```

For the example provided

```
nm1 <- paste0("Q46x47_", seq(1, 5, by = 2))
nm2 <- paste0("Q46x47_", seq(2, 6, by = 2))
```

---

If we need a `dplyr` option, an opiton is to get the column name when we loop `across` the even columns specified in 'nm2', then extract the suffix digits at the end, convert to numeric, subtract 1 to create the odd column name, `get` the value of the column and do the `replace`ment

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(across(all_of(nm2), ~
                {
             tmp <- cur_column()
             replace(., get(str_c('Q46x47_', 
            as.integer(str_extract(tmp, "\\d+$"))-1)) == 0, 0)

           }))
```

-output

```
# Q46x47_1 Q46x47_2 Q46x47_3 Q46x47_4 Q46x47_5 Q46x47_6
#1        1        1        1        1        1        1
#2        2        2        2        2        2        2
#3        0        0        0        0        0        0
#4        1        1        1        1        1        1
#5        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

Comment: Small rep. example provided with only 6 columns. Your code seems to work with it. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I see how the tidyverse approach is quite involved, so I might go with the base R solution. But good to see that it can be done.